# Django form - update boolean field to true

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to up update a boolean field but I got this issue: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'.

I got different issue: at the beginning when seller complete the form it was creating a new channel. I just want to update the current channel.

Logic= consumer create a channel with a seller (channel is not active) -> if seller wants to launch it. he has a form to make it true and launch it.

models:

```
class Sugargroup(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_seller")
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Make it happen', default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True)
```

views:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/cooker/login'),name="dispatch")
class CheckoutDetail(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Sugargroup
    context_object_name = 'sugargroup'
    template_name = 'checkout_detail.html'
    form_class = CreateSugarChatForm
    validation_form_class = LaunchSugargroupForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CheckoutDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        context['validation_form'] = self.get_form(self.validation_form_class) #self.validation_form_class()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sugargroup = self.object
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalid(form)
            
    def form_valide(self, validation_form):
        if validation_form.is_valid():
            validation_form.instance.sugargroup = self.object
            #validation_form.instance.seller = self.request.user
            validation_form.save(update_fields=["is_active"])
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valid(validation_form)
        else:
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalid(validation_form)    

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        validation_form = self.validation_form_class(request.POST) #validation_form = self.get_form(self.validation_form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        elif validation_form.is_valid(): 
            return self.form_valide(validation_form)
        else:
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('checkout:checkout_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

forms

```
class LaunchSugargroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(LaunchSugargroupForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method="post"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field("is_active",css_class="single-input"),
            )
        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit','Launch the channel',css_class="btn btn-primary single-input textinput textInput form-control"))

    class Meta:
        model = Sugargroup
        fields = [
            'is_active'
        ]
```

Comment: Whats `LaunchSugargroupForm`?

Comment: I edit the post :)

Comment: ModelForms don't have an update fields parameter to their [save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L445) method

Comment: @sayse do you have any idea on how I can make it True with LaunchSugargroupForm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validation_form.is_active = True
validation_form.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, :( page reload without change